# Problems Deserializing CookieContainer - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, serialization

I seem to be having an issue deserializing a CookieContainer. It serializes fine, but when I deserialize I am getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at this line below `cookieJar = (CookieContainer)info.GetValue("cookieJar", cookieJar.GetType());`.

But if I uncomment the line that creates a new cookie container, I don't get the error, and the serialized CookieContainer is deserialized.

The cookieJar property is a property of MySession class.

```
public MySession(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    //cookieJar = new CookieContainer()
    cookieJar = (CookieContainer)info.GetValue("cookieJar", cookieJar.GetType());
    email = info.GetString("email");
    password = info.GetString("password");

    client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieJar });
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("cookieJar", cookieJar);
    info.AddValue("email", email);
    info.AddValue("password", password);
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: have you checked if `cookieJar` is null before calling GetType() on it?

Comment: All `NullReferenceException`s are the same: one or more of the objects you "dot into" (for example `info.GetValue()` or `cookieJar.GetTyp()`)  are `null`. Put breakpoints, go debug. Instead of `cookieJar.GetType()` you could try using `typeof(CookieContainer)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the variable `cookieJar` is null in your case so that the call `GetType()` will result in the `NullReferenceException`. You should change the codeline to the following to avoid the exception.

`cookieJar = (CookieContainer)info.GetValue("cookieJar", typeOf(CookieContainer));`

Comment: No it is not null, because when I create an instance of `CookieContainer` prior to deserializing the CookieContainer it works fine and the CookieCollection is present.

Comment: Oh wait. You're correct. What the fudge. Confused now.

Comment: @JamesJeffery There can only be 2 things null at this line. The `SerializationInfo` you get passed to the constructor or the variable `cookieJar` and i think that you will not get a null value for SerializationInfo.